# Switching problem with a LED

Tags: switches, esp8266

I have a basic circuit, with just an LED and a switch between the ground and the RST pin.

When I press the button, the LED glows lightly but RST is not triggered.

Of course if I remove the LED, the ESP will reboot after the switch push.

What I am missing here?

My schematics, but I don't know how to represent the RST pin that is always at 3.3V and should be triggered down to the ground:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faquWT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Overall context: I want to be able to discern a reset triggered out of the deep sleep mode (i.e. pin16 acting as a switch) from a reset triggered manually (with my user switch). To achieve that, my solution is to connect the switch to a gpio and the rst, then to "isolate" the rst from the gpio with a diode (so that rst pin will not change gpio state when triggered from elsewhere).[image]

Comment: Don't wire LEDs with microcontroller without adding some resistor in series with LED.

Comment: LEDs have a voltage drop upwards of 1.7V. This device that you are using probably has internal pul-up resistor on RST. Thus when you push the switch there is still >1.7V at the RST pin which is likely not low enough to reset the deivce.

Comment: Also for the record, please use proper schematics next time...As its really difficult to read these sort of diagrams.

Comment: -1 for the annoying wiring diagram instead of a schematic.

Comment: I will try with a diode intead of a LED, after measuring it, this should be the solution

Comment: @VincentLê Can you clarify *exactly* what you want? So far I think you want to be able to reset the ESP8266 with both GPIO16 and *either* an external push button *or* the push button on the breakout board - which is it? Do you want GPIO16 to reset the device when it is high, or when it is low? Be aware that some MCU output pins default to high on reset, so if you get it round the wrong way the device will continuously reset itself everytime it boots. You want to distinguish between an external and GPIO16 reset with an LED so you can *see* which it is? It's somewhat unclear from your wording.

Comment: @CharlieHanson With one single button, I want to put RST pin to low and an other pin (for instance gpio4) to low. And when I release the button, I want the RST pin back to high, and the other gpio4 must stay to low.

Comment: If you need the input to stay low continuously after the button has been pressed you will need a thyristor and a method of resetting it when it's no longer necessary to keep it low. A better solution may be to use an RC circuit to keep in input pin low for a few seconds - or long enough for the MCU to fully reset and boot up - after which the pin can drift back to high.

Comment: RC seems a good idean, but I am desperately failing to get it working

Answer (score 2):

Looking at you layout, it looks like you have the LED in series with the switch.  If you are trying to get a reset on low and the LED to light at the same time, then connect the LED anode to v+ via a resistor and the cathode to RST. Then connect RST to one side of the switch and 0v to the other side of the switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft6oLQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That is not working any better, but I think this is because of the LED, I will try with a diode

Comment: Data on your device says - "RST - this is the reset pin for the ESP8266, pulled high by default. When pulled down to ground momentarily it will reset the ESP8266 system. This pin is 5V compliant."  There is no way this would not work in this case.  You must have wired it up incorrectly.  Thanks for the schematic Icy.